# Trigonometry Question (finding the sin, cos, cosec etc on a right-angled triangle)

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

For the right-angled triangle $\widehat{PQR}$, where $\overline{PQ} = 9\text{ cm}$, $\overline{QR} = 40\text{ cm}$ and $\overline{PR} = 41\text{ cm}$, give the value of:

a) $\sin \hat{P}$
b) $\cos \hat{R}$
c) $\operatorname{cosec} \hat{P}$
d) $\cot \hat{R}$
e) $\angle \hat{QRP}$
[image]

Comment: An arbitrary triangle doesn't really lend itself to finding these functions. However, there's something special about this particular triangle...

Comment: Are you familiar with how the trig functions are related to the sides of a right triangle?

Comment: Thank you all so much for your detailed answers. This really assisted me in answering further questions now properly understand the steps. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case triangle it is useful to draw our right triangle:
[image]

Now let us remember the trig definitions for any given angle $\theta$: 
$$\begin{align}
\sin(\theta) &= \frac{\mathrm{opposite}}{\mathrm{hypotenuse}}\ \ &\csc(\theta) &= \frac{\mathrm{hypotenuse}}{\mathrm{opposite}}\\
\cos(\theta) &= \frac{\mathrm{adjacent}}{\mathrm{hypotenuse}} &\sec(\theta) &= \frac{\mathrm{hypotenuse}}{\mathrm{adjacent}}\\
\tan(\theta) &= \frac{\mathrm{opposite}}{\mathrm{adjacent}} &\cot(\theta) &= \frac{\mathrm{adjacent}}{\mathrm{opposite}}\\
\end{align}
$$

And so now to solve your problems

> Find the $\sin(\beta)$

We know from above that $\sin(\beta) = \frac{\mathrm{opposite}}{\mathrm{hypotenuse}}$, and so we see that side $\overline{QR}$ is opposite to $\beta$ and our hypotenuse is $\overline{RP}$, so we see that 
$$\sin(\beta) = \frac{40}{41}\ \ .$$

> Find the $\cos(\delta)$

We know from above that $\cos(\delta) = \frac{\mathrm{adjacent}}{\mathrm{hypotenuse}}$, and we observe that $\overline{RQ}$ is adjacent to $\delta$, and ur hypotenuse is $\overline{RP}$, so we see that $$ \cos(\delta) = \frac{40}{41}\ \ .†$$

> Find the $\csc(\beta)$

We know from above that $csc(\beta) = \frac{\mathrm{hypotenuse}}{\mathrm{opposite}}$, and like observed before, $\overline{QR}$ is opposite to $\beta$ and our hypotenuse is $\overline{RP}$, so we see that 
$$\csc(\beta) = \frac{41}{40}\ \ .$$

> Find the $\cot(\delta)$

We know from above that $\cot(\theta) = \frac{\mathrm{adjacent}}{\mathrm{opposite}}$, and we know that $\overline{RQ}$ is adjacent to $\delta$ and $\overline{QP}$ is opposite $\delta$ and so $$\cot(\theta) = \frac{40}{9}\ \ .$$

> Find the angle measure of $\delta $

Finally we have to find the angle measure $\delta$. First let me introduce inverse functions:

Let's say we have some function $f(x) = y$. If we want find what our $x$ is, and we know what $y$ is, we have to take the inverse function written as $f^{-1}(x)$. We define this function as the function that has the property $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$. So for trig functions, if we know (for example) $\sin(\theta) = y$ then $\sin^{-1}(y) = \theta$.†† You may have seen the $\sin^{-1}$, $\cos^{-1}$, and $\tan^{-1}$ buttons on your calculator, and that is what they are. **Just to be fully clear** $\sin^{-1}(x) \not = \frac{1}{\sin(x)}$

Now on to the problem, we know what the $\cos(\delta) = \frac{40}{41}$, and so to find $\delta$ we must take the inverses of both sides:
$$
\begin{align}
\cos^{-1}(\cos(\delta)) &= \cos^{-1}(\frac{40}{41})\\
\delta  &= \cos^{-1}(\frac{40}{41})\\
&\approx 12.68^\circ
\end{align}
$$

That last result is simply evaluated with a calculator.

---

†It is interesting to note that the $\sin(\beta) = \cos(\delta)$, and if we note that $\delta = 90^{\circ} - \beta$ we get the general identity $\sin(\beta) = \cos(90^{\circ} - \beta)$ for any given angle $\beta$

†† The inverse sine (i.e. $\sin^{-1}(\theta)$) is sometimes written as $\arcsin(\theta)$.

Answer (score 0):

$40^2 + 9^2 = 1600 + 81 = 1681$
And $41^2 = 1681$

So this is a right angled triangle (Pythagoras Theorem) 
Hypot =$ 41$
Base = $9$
Perpendicular = $40$

$\sin = \frac{P}{H}$

$\cos = \frac{B}{H}$
...

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Draw a picture.  Use the definition $\sin P=\frac {\text {opposite}}{\text{hypotenuse}}$  You are given all the sides, so .  b,c,d are similar.  For e, you will have an inverse trig function (there are several choices).

Answer (score 0):

Using definition of trigonometric functions from figure

a) $$\sin \hat{P}=\frac{PQ}{PR}=9/41$$
b) $$\cos \hat{R}=\frac{QR}{PR}=40/41$$
c) $$\csc \hat{P}=\frac{1}{\sin \hat{P}}=41/9$$
d) $$\cot \hat{R}=40/9$$
e) $$\angle \hat{QRP}=\arccos(40/41)$$

Comment: I believe your $\sin(\hat{P})$ value is wrong, as $\overline{QR}$ is opposite, not $\overline{PQ}$. (See my answer for a visual)

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that $PQR$ is a right triangle. It would be best to draw a picture first.

[image]

From here, use the definitions of the trig functions to find parts a through d.

$$a) \sin(P) = \frac{\mbox{opposite side}}{\mbox{hypotenuse}}, \quad b) \cos(R) = \frac{\mbox{adjacent side}}{\mbox{hypotenuse}},$$ $$c) \csc(P) = \frac{\mbox{hypotenuse}}{\mbox{opposite side}}, \quad d) \cot(R) = \frac{\mbox{adjacent side}}{\mbox{opposite side}}.$$

For part e, you can find $\angle R$ using the inverse cosine function, $cos^{-1}$ (also called $\arccos$) with the value you found for $\cos(R)$ in part b.